# Catch redirect and return json message if $request->ajax() in Laravel

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware

I'm searching for a way to handle redirects after form submits in Laravel. My controller methods (store/update) have this line at the end:

```
return redirect()->route('admin.templates.edit', ['id' => $template->id]);
```

I would like to intercept this redirect (if possibile) and return a json message if the form is submitted via ajax:

By now I have to write this in every method:

```
if (request()->ajax()) {
    return [
        'redirect' => route('admin.templates.edit', ['id' => $template->id])
    ];
}
return redirect()->route('admin.templates.edit', ['id' => $template->id]);
```

Is there a way to write the "normal" redirect and encapsulate in a json if the request is made via ajax? Maybe with a middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Use middleware for all the routes that you need to intercept Ajax requests in. You can use the code nearly exactly as you have it:

```
if (request()->ajax()) {
return [
    'redirect' => route('admin.templates.edit', ['id' => $template->id])
];
}

return redirect()->route('admin.templates.edit', ['id' => $template->id]);
```

and act accordingly from the middleware.

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (request()->ajax()) {
        return response()->redirect(route('admin.templates.edit', ['id' => $template->id]));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a macro for `RedirectResponse` That take care of ajax you can add it in `AppServiceProvider`

```
RedirectResponse::macro('withAjax', function ()
{
    /* @var $this RedirectResponse */
    return request()->ajax() ? ['redirect' => $this->getTargetUrl()] : $this;
});
```

Now in your controller you can simply use this

`return redirect()->back()->macroCall('withAjax', []);`